# Cannot accept SDK Licenses for android SDK in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

This is my first time running Flutter as I am looking to get started with it. When I try to configure it my apps cant be run because SDK Licenses have not been accepted. When I try to fix that in the suggested way I get the following error :
[Exception Gets Thrown When I Try To Accept Licenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo8M0.png)

How do I fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed a similar issue by deleting the build tools from the Android SDK folder and reinstall it again.